# Unrecognized configuration class <class 'transformers.models.bert.configuration_bert.BertConfig'> for this kind of AutoModel: AutoModelForSeq2SeqLM

Tags: nlp, transform, bert-language-model

Model type should be one of BartConfig, PLBartConfig, BigBirdPegasusConfig, M2M100Config, LEDConfig, BlenderbotSmallConfig, MT5Config, T5Config, PegasusConfig, MarianConfig, MBartConfig, BartConfig, BlenderbotConfig, FSMTConfig, XLMProphetNetConfig, ProphetNetConfig, EncoderDecoderConfig.

I am trying to load a fine-tuned Bert model for machine translation using AutoModelForSeq2SeqLM but it can't recognize the configuration class.

```
from transformers import AutoTokenizer, AutoModelForSeq2SeqLM, Seq2SeqTrainingArguments, Seq2SeqTrainer

model = AutoModelForSeq2SeqLM.from_pretrained('/content/drive/MyDrive/Models/CSE498')
```

**Config File**

```
{
  "_name_or_path": "ckiplab/albert-tiny-chinese",
  "architectures": [
    "BertForMaskedLM"
  ],
  "attention_probs_dropout_prob": 0.0,
  "bos_token_id": 101,
  "classifier_dropout": null,
  "classifier_dropout_prob": 0.1,
  "down_scale_factor": 1,
  "embedding_size": 128,
  "eos_token_id": 102,
  "gap_size": 0,
  "hidden_act": "gelu",
  "hidden_dropout_prob": 0.0,
  "hidden_size": 312,
  "initializer_range": 0.02,
  "inner_group_num": 1,
  "intermediate_size": 1248,
  "layer_norm_eps": 1e-12,
  "max_position_embeddings": 512,
  "model_type": "bert",
  "net_structure_type": 0,
  "num_attention_heads": 12,
  "num_hidden_groups": 1,
  "num_hidden_layers": 4,
  "num_memory_blocks": 0,
  "pad_token_id": 0,
  "position_embedding_type": "absolute",
  "tokenizer_class": "BertTokenizerFast",
  "torch_dtype": "float32",
  "transformers_version": "4.18.0",
  "type_vocab_size": 2,
  "use_cache": true,
  "vocab_size": 30522
}
```

Answer (score 2):

This is because BERT itself is not a seq2seq model. You can consider using a pre-trained BART instead.